# Simple dice roll program issue

Tags: python, random, while-loop, python-3.3, dice

I have created a program where the user can select a certain sided dice then it rolls and outputs the number generated, it then asks if the user wants to roll again and by using a while loop. i have wrote the program and for some reason it keeps on repeating the input dice side number prompt and i don't know why, here is the code

```
import random

roll_agn='yes'
    while roll_agn=='yes':
        dice=input ('Please choose a 4, 6 or 12 sided dice: ')
        if dice ==4:
                print(random.randint(1,4))
        elif dice ==6:
                print(random.randint(1,6))
        elif dice ==12:
                print(random.randint(1,12))
    else:
        roll_agn=input('that is not 4, 6 or 12, would you like to choose again, please answer yes or no') 
    if roll_agn !='yes':
        print ('ok thanks for playing')
```

I suspect it is something to do with the while loop or the indentation, but I have been fiddling with it for like 3o mins and i cant get it to work properly, so if someone could help me out here it would be appreciated, Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The indentation on `else: roll_agn=input` is such that it only runs after you exit the `while` loop - but the `while` loop can never end until you run the `else` clause, therefore infinite loop.

Here is a cleaned-up, better-structured version:

```
# assumes Python 3.x
from random import randint

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))         # if Python 2.x use raw_input instead of input
        except ValueError:
            # not an int
            pass

def get_yn(prompt):
    while True:
        value = input(prompt).strip().lower() # if Python 2.x use raw_input instead of input
        if value in {'y', 'yes'}:
            return True
        elif value in {'n', 'no'}:
            return False

def roll(sides):
    return randint(1, sides)

def main():
    while True:
        sides = get_int("Number of sides on die (4, 6, or 12)? ")

        if sides in {4, 6, 12}:
            print("You rolled a {}".format(roll(sides)))
        else:
            print("U no reed gud?")

        if not get_yn("Play again (y/n)? "):
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As nicer piece of code as it is, this is for a school project and I don't want to turn in someone elses work, i just wanted mine to be fixed so if it is at all possible, i would be really grateful, but thanks for doing this it gives me ideas for my next project !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have indentation problems with the if statements. Try lining up elif with if.

```
if dice ==4:
    print(random.randint(1,4))
elif dice ==6:
    print(random.randint(1,6))
elif dice ==12:
    print(random.randint(1,12))
```

Comment: I have tried lining up the indentations like this but i doesn't solve my issue with an ever repeating 'choose dice sides' print any ideas on that ?

Comment: I think Hugh Bothwell and Tom Fenech both found it. It also looks like you need to line up the else statement so it is with the if block. It does not look like you can change the value of roll_agn in the while block. I'll also note you can use int(dice) in randint(1, int(dice)) and remove the elif statements. Hugh Bothwell has an example in roll(sides).